# How to execute Lambda proxy integration with Cloudwatch Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've already created one lambda function with api-gateway proxy integration by using `aws-lambda-router` npm library. Sample index file is as follow:

```
const router = require('aws-lambda-router');
const myController = require('./controllers/testController');
exports.handler = router.handler({
  proxyIntegration: {
    cors: true,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET',
        action: (request, _) => {
          return myController.test(request);
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/cat',
        method: 'GET',
        action: (request, _) => {
          return myController.cat(request);
        }
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

Problem is I cannot be able to run `/` path of above lambda with Cloudwatch event and I don't want to create another lambda function because of code consistency issue (when one business logic is required to change, I need to change to both lambda fns). Is there anyway that I can run those Lambda proxy integration fn with cloudwatch event?

Comment: `API gateway` is not a valid target for CW Event. What do you want to achieve? Can you use lambda as target?

Comment: Yap, I want Lambda to be target instead of api-gateway. @Marcin